# AJAX added HTML elements aren't added to the DOM?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, dom

Here's the initial page:

[image]

Here is how it looks after the link is clicked.

[image]

Upon examining the source code, it seems the elements aren't placed into it. There should be a div in there no?

[image]

Here's the code that's run when the link is clicked:

```
public ActionResult GetStatus()
{
    return Content("<div>Status OK - " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ".</div>");
}
```

I'm trying to have each newly added `<div>` inside the  `#status` div fade into view, by using this Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Update() {
        $("#status").first().hide().fadeIn();
    }
</script>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Update Status", "GetStatus", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "status", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore, OnSuccess = "Update"})
```

However every time I click the link, the values are fetched and added correctly, but the entire contents of `#status` fade in to view.

I'm guessing this is because the source code isn't updated with the newly added items, and the .first() method isn't finding what it should.

Any ideas?

Comment: CAn you please posy some HTML of the contents of "status" after your AJAX call has run. That may help.

Comment: @Diodeus: That's precisely what I posted above. It's the picture with the yellow highlight. Notice that none of the AJAX result divs are being appended after the AJAX call despite them showing well in the browsers view pane.

Comment: There are no HTML tags inside "status", so "first()" can only find the text that's there. I don't see any DIVs being appended inside.

Comment: @Diodeus: Exactly! That's the problem. What do I do to make the added information appear in the source. I'm guessing that's why the first() method isn't working correctly.

Comment: `.first()` returns the first selector of all the matched selector (useful when the CSS selector matches multiple items and you only want the first one).  It does NOT return the first child object.  You could get the first child object with `.children().first()`, but your sample HTML only has the one div, no child objects at all.

Comment: @jfriend: Thanks! That bit about .children() was the final piece to the puzzle. Should I edit the question with the solution since the actual answer was pretty pieced together by me. It might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have more than one DOM object with the `id="status"`.  If you're repeating this code more than once, then that is a problem.  If you want to have several of them, change the identifier to a class and then the `.first()` call will make some sense.

`$("#status")` will never return more than one object.  And, if you have more than one object with `id="status"`, it will be inconsistent from browser to browser which object you get because it's illegal HTML.

Change the HTML to this:

```
<div class="status">No Status Yet.</div>
```

And then you can use this jQuery with it:

```
$(".status").first().hide().fadeIn();
```

---

**Edit:** As it turns out the OP didn't want the first status div, they wanted the first child div inside the status div.  Insufficient info in the question for any of the answerers to know that until many, many comments were exchanged back and forth.   So, the right answer had to do with fetching the first child.

```
$("#status").children().first().hide().fadeIn();
```

Comment: Please see edit, this has nothing to do with the problem. I edited in more code so the actual problem is more apparent.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia - Are you sure?  You insist on using `$("#status").first()` which means you think that `$("#status")` is going to return more than one object which means you seem to think you have more than one object with that ID.  That is NOT allowed and will make things work inconsistently.

Comment: Or, it may be that you don't understand what `.first()` does.  That gets the first matched selector, not the first child div.  If you're trying to get the first child div, then you perhaps you want `$("#status").children().first()`.  But, this isn't consistent with your sample HTML so I really have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: That was it, see my last comment in the question post. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @Sergio Tapia: Select an answer as correct, the one you think is the closest match to an answer to this question. This helps folks googling for similar solutions. And the people taking some time to answer your question deserve the credit as well.

Comment: @jfriend00: How did I give insufficient info when I explicitly wrote in: `I'm trying to have each newly added <div> inside the #status div fade into view, by using this Javascript:` - That's pretty laid out if you ask me. Seems to me most people read the question about half way through and drew conclusions when everything was spelled out clearly.

Comment: The two things that led me astray were: `$("#status").first()` which led us to believe you wanted the first div with an id="status" and your sample HTML image which showed no children objects inside the status div.  I understand now what was really meant, but with those two clues, the words seemed to conflict with the understanding so far so I didn't pay much attention to the words.  Probably all of our bad for not fully digesting the words too.  Of course, the real issue here is that one of the clues we took our direction from is where the error was.

Comment: In hindsight, if you had shown what the generated HTML looked like (after adding a child node) and clearly stated that you wanted to hide the child node, we all would have gotten there a lot sooner.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript changes to DOM don't appear when you view-source directly, because view-source loads the page newly. To view JS changes you have to use inspection tools, for Firefox there is Firebug. Chrome has a built in tool, right click the div and choose "Inspect element".

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere. The output HTML is as expected when viewed with Firebug. So now I'm stumped. Why is the first() method not returning the first div element, but making everything flash in?

Comment: `hide().fadeIn()` does not wait for hide to complete. They're called one after another. You need `hide( 'fast', function() { $( this ).fadeIn() } )`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've changed my javascript to this: `$("#status").$("div").first().hide('fast', function () { fadeIn() })` but now the div appears with no fade at all. It's my understanding that the Javascript is saying: `From #status, find me all the divs in there, and on the first one, do this:` Is this correct?

Comment: @Sergio Tapia, I think gAMBOOKa gave the correct answer(+1), it should be  in callback. If you still have any problem, please let me know. EDIT: Put your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ > Save and give the link.

Comment: @Usman: Thanks for your time. Yes I'm still having issue with this. Please see my comment directly above yours.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia: I edited my comment. It's `$(this).fadeIn()`, not `fadeIn()`

Comment: Also, look at [Mark's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196616/ajax-added-html-elements-arent-added-to-the-dom/7196815#7196815)

Answer (score 2):

IF you just want to show the first enclosed div do this:

```
$('#status').children().hide().first().fadeIn();
```

as here: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/AeVnp/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `first()` when selecting a node with an ID, as there should only be one anyway.

```
$("#status").hide().fadeIn();
```

That being said, where are you populating the html inside `$('#status')` ? What is `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore` ? Why not just use `$.ajax()` ?

```
function Update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update_status.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text',
        success:function(data){
            $('#status').hide().html(data).fadeIn();
        }
    });
}

$('#my_update_button').click(function(){
    Update();
});
```

Comment: I appreciate that sentiment, but it's not relevant to the problem. Maybe I didn't put the question clear enough. Inside of the #status div, there will be many other divs containing the current server time. That's why I used the first() selector.

Comment: @AlienWebguy is right. [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) selects the first item from an array of elements.

Comment: Guys.  `$("#status")` and `$("#status").first()` and `$("#status").eq(0)` and `$("#status").get(0)` are all completely equivalent because "#status" never matches more than one thing - it's an ID - only ever one of them in a page and only one ever returned even if there are more (illegal HTML).

Comment: Actually, that's not right either. `eq(0)` is the same as `first()`. You need `.children().first()`

Comment: @gamebooka - Yeah, that's what I thought in my other comments too.  Except there are no child objects in his status div that I see.  We're apparently not getting enough info to know what the real question/issue is.

Comment: Ya my bad - `$('#status').children(':first-child').hide().fadeIn();`